# Python: How do I pass name of a dataframe to a function in a for loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, variables

```
for cnt in range (2,Maxcnt):
    X="DF"+ str(cnt)
    matchparts(DF1, X)
    print(X)
```

I want to send DF2 to DFn to matchparts function.. I tried sending it using matchparts(DF1, "DF"+ str(cnt)) the function recieves it as string rather than a DF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically 3 ways in which you can do this :

1. Using dictionary
2. Using `globals()`
3. Using eval(Not recommended)

Say you have dataframe in multiple variables, say `DF1, DF2, DF3.`

##### Using dictionary

To access them using the string name created on the run, you can store them in a dictionary at the first place.

eg

```
result = {
'DF1':DF1,
'DF2':DF2,
'DF3':DF3,
}
```

Now you can call your function as

```
for cnt in range (2,Maxcnt):
    X="DF"+ str(cnt)
    matchparts(DF1, result[X])
    print(result[X])
```

##### Using globals

You can do the same using `globals()` in python

`globals()['DF1']` or `globals()['DF2']` should give you the same.

So your function call would become

```
matchparts(DF1, globals()[X])
```

###### Example code

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'data':[1,2]})
>>> df1
   data
0     1
1     2
>>> globals()['df1']
   data
0     1
1     2
```

##### Using eval

*Disclaimer : Not recommended due to security issue*

Using eval your function call would become

```
matchparts(DF1, eval(X))
```

###### Example code

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'data':[1,2]})
>>> eval('df1')

   data
0     1
1     2
```

Comment: Perfect.! globals() worked like a charm!

Comment: glad! I could help you @Sachin